# Is `Body.json()` faster than `JSON.parse(responseText)` for JSON received from `fetch`?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

Is [Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) faster than [JSON.parse(responseText)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for JSON received from [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)?

Theoretically `Body.json()` can start decoding JSON as soon as it receives the first bytes from the [ReadableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) from `fetch`. 
Is this how it works? Or does it wait until all bytes are received?

```js
const response = await fetch(url);
const json = await response.json();
```

```js
const response = await fetch(url);
const text = await response.text();
const json = JSON.parse(text);
```

So, is there a difference between these versions of the code?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: The `fetch()` promise won't be resolved until the entire response body is received.

Comment: Why does this even matter?

Comment: Are you sure? As I know, the `fetch()` promise resolves as soon as the headers is received, and it allows you to get `ReadableStream` to read it manually, for example, to create a downloading process indicator.

Comment: It's just interesting for me. Is there an optimisation or no. I did not test it.

Comment: Also the simple way to check it is to use `json` method on an invalid JSON data, with the enabled network throttling in DevTools. The error appears only after the entire response's `body` was received. So, `json` method does **not** parse the `body` in stream way — while downloading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right that the body gets consumed while fetching (and that the body is a stream), but per specs, when the browser is to [*consume the body*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body), it [has to](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-concept-read-all-bytes-from-readablestream) [read all bytes](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-read-all-bytes-from-readablestream) from this stream with a stream reader **before** it can "*[r]eturn the result of transforming promise by a fulfillment handler that returns the result of the package data algorithm*".

This means that before [`Body.json()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-parse-json-from-bytes) can even call its first step [utf-8-decode](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-utf-8-decode%E2%91%A2), the full body must already have been read as an Uint8Array, and the same applies to all [package data types](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-package-data).

Then we can conclude that

```
fetch( url )
  .then( body => body.json() );
```

is actually syntactic sugar for

```
fetch( url )
  .then( body => body.arrayBuffer() )
  .then( bytes => new TextDecoder().decode( bytes ) )
  .then( text => JSON.parse( text ) );
```

and that

```
fetch( url )
  .then( body => body.text() );
```

is itself syntactic sugar for

```
fetch( url )
  .then( body => body.arrayBuffer() )
  .then( bytes => new TextDecoder().decode( bytes ) )
```

And thus if you add yourself the `.then( text => JSON.parse( text ) )`, you actually have exactly the same operations being performed.